# Should we have tags for individual languages?

Tags: discussion

We seem to be acquiring tags for many individual languages. While I accept it may be useful to have tags for a few highly significant languages I'm not sure we need a tag for every language.

Answer (score 2):

You're right, we don't need all of them. They're around 6000 languages so... :P

Luckily the method of tag creation helps us: you can create tags only by posting questions so the system already controls what tags can be there and which ones are not needed.

A good rule of thumb to avoid thousands of tags with many dupes is to choose an existing tag and if a new one is required, it should be not too broad and not too narrow so that it can cover a reasonable range of notions.

Comment: Thanks, that's reasonable; but tags are being created for individual languages, should we reject them as a matter of policy? Should we allow tags for a few particularly important languages? (and, should I add these questions to my original question?)

Comment: @GastonÜmlaut Let me answer in order: There already are language tags and I don't think they're harmful at the moment. If we start to gain traction and get many many then we can re-think it and only allow families but it's really a remote thing. Important languages... how do we decide that? It's necessarily going to bother someone so use tags for the languages treated in the question and if we ever get a problem in the future, we'll see. :D About your last question: Yeah, this way someone else could address those when answering here. :)

Comment: Ok, just counted: at the moment we have 36 tags for individual languages.

Comment: Why not have a tag for "specific language"?    Any further specification can appear in the question itself.

Comment: @JamesGrossmann You mean get rid of all "language" tags? That would not be in our favor either, since tags are meant to be used also to classify questions and to "search" through these classifications. If you remove that you won't be able to search effectively for a certain language. I say, let's keep the most commonly asked languages and so on: the system will do this by itself. :)

Comment: @Alenanno:  Then it's hard to see a way out of having a tag for each specific language discussed, e.g. for English, German, Basque, Ainu, Mandarin, and so on.   Would this present any difficulties?

Comment: @JamesGrossmann Right now, we don't have any. Should too many tags be created then we might have a problem. Do you think we should just use tags like "Romance-languages" and then specify in the question if it's Italian or Spanish or French etc?